# Nice names for array values in attributes for Laravel 5.4

Tags: laravel

Laravel receives data in this format

```
['roles' => [1, 4]]
```

Rules

```
$rules = ['roles.*' => 'integer|min:1|exists:roles,id']
```

When Validator fails it shows

```
[
 "roles.0" => [
   "The roles.0 must be an integer.",
 ],
```

]

How can I make it automatically convert `all` such cases into array of errors with key (in this case) `roles`. There will be many such validators and it will be copy-paste to do foreach for every such case.

Comment: try to replace integer with `numeric`

Answer (score 1):

You could try to edit `resources/view/en/validation.php` (assuming you want to do this for an english website) and modify attributes section (at the end of the file) like this:

```
'attributes' => [
    'roles.0' => 'Admin', 
    'roles.1' => 'Moderator',
    // etc.
],
```

One other solution (if you want to avoid duplication) could be to write a small blade with your rules:

```
@foreach ($errors->get('roles.*') as $message)
    // Do what you want with some @if
@endforeach
```

Then just include this in your different pages:

```
@if ($errors)
    @include('roles-error-messages')
@endif
```